# Getting value from HTML code in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Just a short, quick question:

how can I get value (like in `<input type="hidden" id="sth" value="something">`) to be seen by C#'s @if statement?
I want to have it like `@if(sth.value=="notthesamething")`

Comment: are you familiar with `<% %>` in html markup..? you could also add the `runat ="server"` attribute as well

Comment: If it's C# in order for the serer side @if to work, it would need to be part of some server side model.  If you want to check the value, it should be `@if(model.myproperty == true)`.  If you want to read it on the client, you can use JavaScript to read the input value but I wouldn't read the value of an input from the server in a view, doesn't make sense...

Comment: @paqogomez - it's not webforms.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to combine RAZOR code with html.  You can't do this.

Once the code is served to the client, all of the RAZOR code has already run.  You would need to do this in javascript.